# how to get the price value after selecting the the product size in amazon using python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm building web scraper website and I have a problem about extracting price of the product in amazon.

here is the url: [https://www.amazon.com/Viishow-Printed-Dresses-Pockets-Wine/dp/B07PNGB9H3/ref=sr_1_3?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1560098637&s=fashion-womens-intl-ship&sr=1-3&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PNGB9H3)

NOTE: This URL is without selecting size with two prices ex: $16.99 - $22.99

when I select the size, it gives me the exactly price of the product with size selected but when I scrape it using python it gives me the range prices ($16.99 - $22.99) not $22.99

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.amazon.com/Viishow-Printed-Dresses-Pockets-Wine/dp/B07PMHY51F/ref=sr_1_3?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1560098637&s=fashion-womens-intl-ship&sr=1-3&th=1&psc=1"
# This URL with selected size with the product price ex: $22.99 but when I run the program it gives me two prices: $16.99 - $22.99 not this price: $22.99

res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()

print(price)
```

Now it should extract the output price = $22.99 but it extract output price = $16.99 - $22.99

can you help me on this please?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change parser and used a different id

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.amazon.com/Viishow-Printed-Dresses-Pockets-Wine/dp/B07PMHY51F/ref=sr_1_3?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1560098637&s=fashion-womens-intl-ship&sr=1-3&th=1&psc=1"
# This URL with selected size with the product price ex: $22.99 but when I run the program it gives me two prices: $16.99 - $22.99 not this price: $22.99

res = requests.get(URL, headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
price = soup.select_one('#priceblock_ourprice').text
print(price)
```